# Does Ethereum Wallet need a separate update of Geth on a Mac

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

(1) When the Ethereum Wallet is upgraded to 0.9.3 and then opened, it prompts to upgrade to a new version of Geth. Although it's on a Mac computer, the Geth version it suggests is type "amd/64", which is a type associated with Windows computers. Should the "amd/64" version be downloaded on a Mac, skip it or what other action should be done?

(2) What is the role of the Ethereum Wallet download versus the separate download of Geth (i.e. what does each application do)?

(3) Does the installation of the latest Ethereum Wallet also need the current version of Geth?

(4) Is the current version of Geth required for the Ethereum Wallet to fork to the Byzantium blockchain and continue downloading blocks past 4,370,000?

I am referring to the Ethereum Wallet releases found here: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to research these issues, this is what I discovered:

(1) Yes - the Geth amd/64 version that the Ethereum Wallet suggests to download is the correct one for Mac OSX.

(2) Ethereum Wallet is a user interface that interacts with Geth, so they work together and both are required for Ethereum Wallet to work. It is important to be on the latest update of both Ethereum Wallet and Geth. I am interested in understanding more of the technical details of how this happens and what each does. Please comment to provide more clarification.

(3) Yes - both are required, so Geth updates suggested by Ethereum Wallet should be done, especially when there is a hard-fork imminent.

(4) Yes - in Ethereum Wallet go to the top toolbar and select "Ethereum Wallet" and then "Check for Ethereum node updates" to search for the latest Geth version that relates to your installation of Ethereum Wallet. Then proceed with the download.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) What is the role of the Ethereum Wallet download versus the
>   separate download of Geth (i.e. what does each application do)?

Ethereum Wallet is a dAPP and it needs a node to run, so you have geth running the blockchain so the dAPP can run over it.

Mist is an explorer which also works over a geth node.